# Unifi UDM - IPSec VPN PING works but nothing else?

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, ubiquiti, unifi

I'm trying to setup a remote syslog solution that is comprised of the following:

Unifi UDM SE --> Site-to-site IPSec VPN Connection --> AWS VPC --> Private EC2 Instance (syslog collector - Internal IP: 10.0.2.113)

I have been able to successfully establish the IPSec VPN tunnel between the on-prem UDM and AWS, and am able to successfully PING the EC2 instance directly from the UDM itself (after SSHing in). However, despite being able to SSH into the private EC2 instance perfectly fine from my laptop which is connected to the LAN that the UDM is managing (i.e. the UDM is my local LAN's gateway), I am simply unable to SSH (or indeed, access any UDP/TCP port) from the UDM itself, and I cannot fathom why.

Obviously routing must be working, otherwise I wouldn't be able to ping, and I'm assuming the UDM firewall must be allowing access, otherwise I wouldn't be able to SSH the private EC2 instance from my laptop connected to the same LAN as the UDM?

Despite trying everything under the sun I can think of, I can't get this to work, and I need this to work so that the UDM itself is able to publish syslog messages over the IPSec VPN.

Unifi OS version: UniFi OS UDM SE 3.0.18